# How can I make it so that my form requires certain fields

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make a Spring Boot project that works like an e-commerce website.

In the forms for creating and editing a product, I want to make it so that all fields are required, because if I do not input a price, then I get the "Whitelabel Error Page: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback." error.

Main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ProductController

```java
/**This is the product controller class. It has different mappings as well as the methods that allow 
 * the user to perform the different CRUD operations with regard to the products. */
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/product")
    public String product(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.findAll());

        return "product";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String create(Model model) {
        return "create";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String save(@RequestParam String prodName, @RequestParam String prodDesc, @RequestParam Double prodPrice, @RequestParam String prodImage) {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProdName(prodName);
        product.setProdDesc(prodDesc);
        product.setProdPrice(prodPrice);
        product.setProdImage(prodImage);
        
        productRepository.save(product);
        
        return "redirect:/show/" + product.getId();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/show/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("product", productRepository.findById(id).get());
       
        return "show";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@RequestParam String id) {
        Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(id);
        productRepository.delete(product.get());

        return "redirect:/product";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("product", productRepository.findById(id).get());
        
        return "edit";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String update(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String prodName, @RequestParam String prodDesc, @RequestParam Double prodPrice, @RequestParam String prodImage) {
        Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(id);
        
        product.get().setProdName(prodName);
        product.get().setProdDesc(prodDesc);
        product.get().setProdPrice(prodPrice);
        product.get().setProdImage(prodImage);
        
        productRepository.save(product.get());

        return "redirect:/show/" + product.get().getId();
    }
}
```

Product POJO

```java
@Document(collection = "products")
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    String id;
    
    String prodName;
    String prodDesc;
    Double prodPrice;
    String prodImage;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String prodName, String prodDesc, Double prodPrice, String prodImage) {
        this.prodName = prodName;
        this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
        this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
        this.prodImage = prodImage;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProdName() {
        return prodName;
    }

    public void setProdName(String prodName) {
        this.prodName = prodName;
    }

    public String getProdDesc() {
        return prodDesc;
    }

    public void setProdDesc(String prodDesc) {
        this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
    }

    public Double getProdPrice() {
        return prodPrice;
    }

    public void setProdPrice(Double prodPrice) {
        this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
    }

    public String getProdImage() {
        return prodImage;
    }

    public void setProdImage(String prodImage) {
        this.prodImage = prodImage;
    }
}
```

create.html form page

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="default">
    <head>
        <title>Create Product</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
            
                <h3>
                    <a href="/product" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>Product List</a>
                </h3>
                
                <h2>Create Product</h2>
                
                <form action="/save">
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="prodDesc" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Price</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="prodPrice" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Image URL:</label>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="prodImage" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit.html form page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="default">
    <head>
        <title>Edit Product</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
            
                <h3>
                    <a href="/product" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>Product List</a>
                </h3>
                
                <h2>Edit Product</h2>
                
                <form action="/update">
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" th:value="${product.prodName}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="prodDesc" cols="60" rows="3" th:text="${product.prodDesc}"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Price</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="prodPrice" th:value="${product.prodPrice}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Image URL:</label>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="prodImage" th:value="${product.prodImage}" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${product.id}" />
                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ecommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-website</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-website</name>
    <description>Ecommerce website using Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried looking on different forms, and I saw answers that involved using annotations like @NotNull or creating a configuration class, but neither of those have worked for me.

Comment: You can try using the HTML `required` attribute for the form input fields.

Comment: Add `required` on the HTML side and add `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency and add the validations uou need `@NotNUll`/`@NotBlank` and add `@Valid` on the method argument in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency. Add the annotations to your `Product` and use `Product` as a model object instead of requst parameters.

```java
@RequestMapping("/save")
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute Product product) {
    productRepository.save(product);
    return "redirect:/show/" + product.getId();
}
```

```java
@Document(collection = "products")
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    String id;
    
    @NotBlank
    String prodName;
    @NotBlank
    String prodDesc;
    @Min(0.01d)
    Double prodPrice;
    String prodImage;
```

Some of that for validation (ofcourse you would need to determine which to use based on your requirements.

Additionally use proper types and `required` keyword in your HTML templates.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Product Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="prodDesc">Product Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="prodDesc" cols="60" rows="3" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="prodPrice">Product Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="prodPrice" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="prodImage">Product Image URL:</label>
    <input type="url" class="form-control" name="prodImage" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Adding the required keyword to the html code helped me out. However, when I try to add what you said about the Valid annotation, I get an error saying "Valid cannot be resolved to a type." The same thing is happening when I try using the NotBlank and Min annotations. Do you know why that is happening? And are they necessary to use when the required keyword in the html code has helped me accomplish the task of requiring the fields?

Comment: Also, if I want to make the fields have a maximum length, how would I go about doing that? I tried using the Size, Length, and Column annotations, but again, Eclipse was telling me that they cannot be "Resolved to a type."

Comment: As I stated and showed in the answer you need `spring-boot-starter-validation` as dependency.  (It is literally the first sentence of my answer).  WIthout that dependency you won't have the annotations nor a concrete validator implementation. For the length use what you tried (but apparently you skipped all the text and only did the code).

Comment: Thanks! I did read your text, and I had originally added the validation to my pom.xml, but I have been reading different sources and changing my code a lot, so I had accidentally removed my validation dependency.